# Cauchy-Schwarz-like inequality for the wedge product

Tags: linear-algebra, cauchy-schwarz-inequality, multilinear-algebra, exterior-algebra

Summary of my question: Does $\| \mathbf a \wedge \mathbf b\| \leq \| \mathbf a \| \| \mathbf b\|$ hold for all $\mathbf a \in \Lambda^k(\mathbb R^n)$ and $\mathbf b \in \Lambda^\ell(\mathbb R^n)$?

Some background: Given $\mathbb R^n$ with the standard inner product, we can define an inner product on the exterior powers $\Lambda^k(\mathbb R^n)$ by $\langle u_1 \wedge \cdots \wedge u_k, v_1 \wedge \cdots \wedge v_k\rangle = \det(\langle u_i, v_j\rangle)_{i,j=1}^k$ and then extending by linearity. As usual, for $\mathbf a \in \Lambda^k(\mathbb R^n)$, let $\|\mathbf a\| = \sqrt{\langle \mathbf a, \mathbf a \rangle}$. If $\mathbf a = u_1 \wedge \cdots \wedge u_k$ (i.e., if $\mathbf a$ is simple), then $\|\mathbf a \|$ is equal to the volume of the $k$-dimensional parallelotope generated by $u_1, \ldots, u_k$.

When $\mathbf a$ and $\mathbf b$ are simple, then we can see that $\| \mathbf a \wedge \mathbf b\| \leq \| \mathbf a \| \| \mathbf b\|$ holds by using the geometric interpretation given above.

When $\mathbf a = u_1 \wedge \cdots \wedge u_k + v_1 \wedge \cdots \wedge v_k$ and $\mathbf b$ is simple, then after some lengthy computations (expanding the inner product and Gram-Schmidt), I was able to show the inequality holds in this case as well.

Is the inequality  $\| \mathbf a \wedge \mathbf b\| \leq \| \mathbf a \| \| \mathbf b\|$ true in general? And is there a geometric interpretation of these quantities when $\mathbf a$ and $\mathbf b$ are not simple?

Comment: [Is this relevant?](https://cuhkmath.wordpress.com/2017/05/20/the-cauchy-schwarz-inequality-and-the-lagrange-identity/)

Comment: @ClementC. The blog post you linked to generalizes Cauchy-Schwarz in a different direction from the inequality in my question. (It also only deals with simple tensors.)

Comment: In $\mathbb{R}^3$ we have $\|a\wedge b\|=\|a\|\|b\|\left|\sin \theta\right|$ where $\theta$ is the angle between $a$ and $b$, so Cauchy-Schwarz holds. Of course equality is not attained by parallel vectors, rather by orthogonal vectors.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio Yes, that falls under the case when $\mathbf a$ and $\mathbf b$ are simple tensors.

Comment: @user10354138 Are you saying for that for any two elements $\mathbf a, \mathbf b$ of the exterior algebra $\Lambda(\mathbb R^n)$, we have $\|\mathbf a \wedge \mathbf b\| \leq \| \mathbf a \mathbf b \| \leq \|\mathbf a\| \| \mathbf b\|$, where the middle expression is the Clifford product? I tried to search for this inequality but I couldn't find it stated anywhere.

Comment: Is there anything wrong with using an orthogonal basis and extending your inequality for simple tensors? 
$\| (\sum_I a_I e^I) \wedge e^K\| = \sum_I |a_I|\cdot \|e^I\wedge e^K\|\leq \sum_I|a_I|\cdot \|e^I\|\cdot\|e^K\|=\|\sum_I a_Ie^I\|\|e^K\|$

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar question, and found a general bound [here](http://webdoc.sub.gwdg.de/ebook/diss/2003/fu-berlin/1999/57/kap2.pdf) (p. 9, equation 1.10) given by
$$
\|\mathbf{a} \wedge \mathbf{b}\| \le \begin{pmatrix} k + \ell \\ k \end{pmatrix}^{1/2} \|\mathbf{a}\|\|\mathbf{b}\|.
$$
The proof of this fact can be found [here](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007/978-3-642-62010-2.pdf) (Geometric Measure Theory, Federer: Section 1.7.5).